# Delete entire table row in vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, events, dom, html-table

I have a HTML table (table2) that is dynamically populated with copies of rows (rowData) from another table (table1) when an 'add' button on table1 is clicked.

The table2 rows include a 'remove' button - so if the user clicks 'remove', I need to remove the entire row corresponding to that button.

So far, I have added an onclick attribute with the innerHTML, but I'm struggling to create a successful remove() function that deletes the clicked row!

```
addToFavourites(someData);

// someData will look like this:

// <tr class='resultRow'>
//  <td>text1</td>
//  <td>text2</td>
//   <td>text3</td>
// </tr> 

const addToFavourites = rowData => {
    let table2Row = document.createElement("tr");
    table2Row.innerHTML = 
`${rowData.innerHTML}<td class='cell'><button type='button' onclick='remove()' class='remove-btn'>Remove</button></td>
`;
    table2.appendChild(table2Row);
  };
```

Comment: Could you also post the related HTML code?

Comment: Edited to show the typical rowData parameter, all other html is added in addFavourites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need the delete button to reference something, like an ID or a class, or perhaps `event.target.parentElement....` (assuming the button's event target is the button itself) and each row has its own button. Since you don't have unique IDs in your code, I'll attempt to make this work with what you have.

```
const remove = (event) => {
  // the first parentElement is <td>, then second is <tr>
  event.target.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
}

const addToFavourites = rowData => {
  let table2Row = document.createElement("tr");
  table2Row.innerHTML = `${rowData.innerHTML}<td class='cell'><button type='button' onclick='remove()' class='remove-btn'>Remove</button></td>`;
  table2.appendChild(table2Row);
};
```

Comment: Thank you! The parentElement.parentElement was what I needed :)